# sql query to extract unique records

Tags: mysql, sql-server

suppose my table contains only 2 fields , ID and product and say my structure looks like this

1       microsoft

0      cisco

2       cisco

3      vmware

0      adobe

0      microsoft

I need to write a query that lists records having **id=0** but only,

**0      adobe**

because the other two products miocrsoft and cisco have one other record that does have an ID and so I can exclude them.

I hope I am clear about what Im trying to achieve. Please let me know if this can be accomplished in sql

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? sql server <> mysql

Comment: MySQL xor SQLServer, please

Comment: sql server .. sorry for the late response

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible using basic aggregation. Notice how I posted consumable data? This is something you should do. It took me far longer to create usable data than it did to write the query.

```
with something(Col1, Col2) as
(
    select 1, 'microsoft' union all
    select 0, 'cisco' union all
    select 2, 'cisco' union all
    select 3, 'vmware' union all
    select 0, 'adobe' union all
    select 0, 'microsoft'
)

select Col2
from something
group by Col2
having MAX(Col1) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id, product
FROM mytable AS t1
WHERE id = 0 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM mytable AS t2
                             WHERE t1.product = t2.product AND t2.id <> 0)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c8e3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = 0 and product not in
(
    SELECT product
    FROM table
    WHERE id <> 0
)
```

Comment: This works but isn't terribly efficient as it has to hit the base table twice. Also there is the nonSARGable <> predicate in the where clause.

Comment: The query optimizer is almost definitely going to be able to hit the base table once, but I do agree with your second point. However, for this case, it won't be much of a performance hit.

Comment: Certainly not if the table only has a few rows. :)

Comment: my table has aroun 2000000 rows eaasily. is there any other better solution

Comment: Use @SeanLange answer if you want

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to get the answer:
In the first part of the code to get all products.
The second part the same products set an array.
In the end, the same products removed from the products of their ID 0

("my database name = stackoverflow" , "my table name = stack" , "my fields = id,name")

```
<?php 
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die ("erorr");
mysql_select_db('stackoverflow');
$query1 = "SELECT name FROM stack";
$result = mysql_query($query1);
echo "<b>Show the products:</b>";
echo "<br>";
$y;
$z;
$i = 0;
$k = 0;
while ($x = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $x[0];
    echo "<br>";
    $y[$i] = $x[0];
    if ($i > 0) {
        for ($j=0; $j < $i; $j++) { 
            if ($y[$i] == $y[$j]) {
                if ($k > 0) {
                    for ($q=0; $q < $k; $q++) { 
                        if ($z[$q] == $y[$i]) {
                        break 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $z[$k] = $y[$i];
                $k++;
                break 1;
            }
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
echo "<hr>";
echo "<b>Show duplicate products:</b>";
echo "<br>";
$k=0;
while (isset($z[$k])) {
    echo $z[$k];
    $k++;
echo "<br>";
}
$query2 = "SELECT name FROM stack WHERE id=0";
$result = mysql_query($query2);
echo "<hr>";
echo "<b>Show answers:</b>";
echo "<br>";
while ($x = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!in_array($x[0], $z)) {
    echo $x[0];
    echo "<br>";
    }
}
 ?>
```

But this kind of response, is not optimized and table bad design. Because every table should have a primary key and search on table by key.