# SELECT/NOT EXISTS unique records with a 'condition'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unique, where-clause

My table contains only 2 columns `ID` and `product` and looks like this:

```
ID      Product
----------------- 
1       microsoft
0       cisco
2       cisco
7       cisco
3       vmware
0       adobe
0       microsoft
```

I need to write a query that lists records having id=0 only,

```
ID      Product
---------------
0       adobe
```

The reason I do not want to list

```
ID      Product
----------------
0       micrsoft
0       cisco
```

is because they have one or more records which does have a product ID.

Tried this:

```
SELECT 
    [ProductID], [Product]
FROM [table] AS t1
WHERE ProductID = 0
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM [table] AS t2
                    WHERE t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID
                      AND t2.ProductID <> 0)
```

seems to take a long time to query. (table has 2 000 000 records)

Comment: Why are you asking the exact same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484775/sql-query-to-extract-unique-records/31484829?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple `group by` with a `having` clause:

```
select 0 as id, product
from [table] t
group by product
having min(id) = 0 and max(id) = 0;
```

Comment: This works. Thanks :D

Comment: if i were to select 3 other columns from the same table is it possible to include it in the query?

Comment: @vardha . . . You can select them using aggregation functions . . . `min(col1), . . .`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to join on Product instead of ProductID:

```
SELECT  [ProductID],[Product]
FROM   [table] as t1 
where ProductID=0 
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM [table] AS t2 
  where  t1.Product=t2.Product 
  AND t2.ProductID<>0
)
```

This translates to "where there exists no other row where the product has the same name, with an ID other than 0".

Comment: is there any other easier way than to use 2 select statements?

Comment: Not easier, no.   You could also do it with a self-join, but that would probably be slower.